# Problems running tests using pytest - Not finding a module within my own package

Tags: python, import, module, package, pytest

### Setup

First, here is the file structure:

```
BankParser
|--BankParser
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- DatabaseManager.py
|   |-- utilities.py
|--Tests
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- test_DatabaseManager.py
```

In test_DatabaseManager.py, I have:
`import BankParser.DatabaseManager as dbm`

I call pytest in the following way, from the VSCode integrated command line:
`pipenv run pytest --verbosity=1 --color=auto --junit-xml=Output\\TestsReport.xml --no-cov Tests`

### Problem

Calling pytest in the above way results in this:

```
Tests\test_DatabaseManager.py:3: in <module>
    import BankParser.DatabaseManager as dbm
BankParser\DatabaseManager.py:5: in <module>
    import utilities as u
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utilities'
```

As you can guess, in DatabaseManager.py, we have
`import utilities.py as u`

### Question

**Why is this import not resolved?** I thought it should be handled in the context of the BankParser package? Using utilities from within DatabaseManager works properly in itself, just shows up as an issue when calling from Tests.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I'm reading this correctly, it sounds like `utilities` is under same parent as `DatabaseManager`, so you can either do an absolute import:
`import BankParser.utilities as u`
or, you can use a relative import:
`import .utilities as u`

The issue is that `utilities.py` itself is not in `PYTHONPATH`, so you can't just import it straight-up.

Comment: Absolute import does resolve this problem, I was under the impression that it shouldn't have to be done within the active package. I'll look into appending to python path. After adding the absolute import however, debugging DatabaseManager.py for example says that BankParser is not a Module. I've been fighting this back and forth between being able to execute the code without Module errors and running tests without Module errors. I can't seem be able to do both lol

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [@ZaketyZach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3660087/zaketyzach), adding my BankParser folder to PYTHONPATH was the solution. Since mine was not set to anything, adding this to my settings.json was fine (VSCode):

```
  "terminal.integrated.env.windows":
  {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}\\BankParser",
  },
```